# How to open a new window on button click in Cocoa Mac Application?

Tags: cocoa, macos, xib

I want to know how to open a new window on button click in Cocoa Mac Programming. Help me. I am doing a mac application which needs to open a new mac window on particular button click.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you want to create a separate class for New Window, these are the steps:

1. Create a class which is a sub class of NSWindowController e.g. NewWindowController
2. Create a window xib for NewWindowController class.
3. On button click code as:

   ```
   NewWindowController *windowController = [[NewWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"You Window XIB Name"];
   [windowController showWindow:self];
   ```

Comment: thank you... it worked well... :) you explained well... thank you... I was looking for a few days and now it worked great... :)

Comment: I've tried the same thing, but the problem that I'm having is that the  new window closes immediately after being displayed. I have no code in there whatsoever so I don;t see what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: @Interfector i am having the same problem .. did u figure it out ?

Comment: Nope :| I'll figure it out sooner or later and I'll post the solution here.

Comment: @Interfector: The reason your window is immediately closing is possibly due to ARC. If you haven't assigned your window controller to a strongly held variable it will be freed immediately after the function ends.

Comment: @iain: good point—as written above, the instance of `NewWindowController` in this answer still won't "stick" unless `controllerWindow` is, e.g., held in an instance variable outside the context of these two lines.

Comment: Wanted to thank the poster of this answer... I was close (but still missed the mark) in my code using [[CustomWindowController alloc] init] instead of the -initWithWindowNibName:.  This answer helped me!

Comment: @iain: I have held my objects strong enough but still NSWindowController closes immediately. Please help.

Answer (score 13):

```
NSWindowController * wc=[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"your_nib_name"];
[wc showWindow:self];
```

Comment: @Saurabh-wow! thanks a bunch! it's worked... thank you... I am new to stackoverflow and it's pretty much impressive... :)

Comment: actually i was looking for the same for the past few days! :) I tried different but didn't subclass NSWindowController!!!

Comment: Why was the sub-classing answer more highly rated than this one? Surely not subclassing is a simpler, more elegant answer?

Comment: Getting Use of undeclared identifier 'self' here, using this inside main.m

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 3**: In your storyboard go to WindowController -> Identity inspector -> storyBoardID: fill out: mainWindow.
Then from your current viewcontroller link the button on the storyboard to the following method:

```
@IBAction func newWindow(_ sender: Any) {
    let myWindowController = self.storyboard!.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "mainWindow") as! NSWindowController
    myWindowController.showWindow(self)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> 1. Create a class which is a sub class of NSWindowController e.g. NewWindowController
> 2. Create a window xib for NewWindowController class.
> 3. On button click code as:
>
>    `NewWindowController *controllerWindow = [[NewWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"You Window XIB Name"];
>      [controllerWindow showWindow:self];`

Yes, but the window closes if this code is inside of some func.
Here is solution.

In `blah.h`

```
@interface blah : NSObject {
     ...
     NewWindowController *controllerWindow;
     ...
}
```

In `blah.m`

```
@implementation
...
   -(IBAction)openNewWindow:(id)sender {
       controllerWindow = [[NewWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"You Window XIB Name"];
       [controllerWindow showWindow:self];
    }
...
```

Comment: It's preferable to add a comment to the existing answer (when you are able) rather than quoting it, responding, and then posting your own.

Comment: @AdrianWragg, yes, i am the newbie, so i'm sorry for that.

Comment: Well... and how can I close the previous one? This code keeps two windows openned at once.

Comment: The problem with this, is that it doesn't emable to have multiple instances of the same window class open at once. For example say you have a text editor app and you want to view multiple text files at once. With this approach, as soon as you open the a new text file, the old window will instantly disappear, because you are overriding the current window controller instance with a new one.