# Pop up window dialogs

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

In Cocoa, my application's main window has a button. How can I make it so when you click it, a new window will be generated and *set focus to such window* so that the main window can not be clicked or interacted with at all? This new window will have a textfield and a submit button. You click it and the window is supposed to close and send the textfield's data back to the main window (and it will recover focus as well).

I found this: [How to open a new window on button click in Cocoa Mac Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547741/how-to-open-a-new-window-on-button-click-in-cocoa-mac-application)

But the answer doesn't seem to be working for me. The function `showWindow` doesn't seem to be recognized...

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create a modal window.

You can see the documentation at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/UsingModalWindows.html for the full details.

Assuming you have created the window in your nib and can access it via an Outlet, you can call

`[NSApp runModalForWindow:myWindowOutletVariable];`

to make it modal like you want.

Comment: …and bear in mind that modal windows [should be avoided if possible](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-BACFBACB). Modal windows are not expected behaviour on Mac OS X. Use a [sheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html) instead.